# Send new exception if a SELECT value returned is NULL or does not exist in the Table

Tags: c#, web-services, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures

So i am using a stored procedure to select a registry from a DB, the only thing the stored procedure does is SELECT ... The thing is that i use that stored procedure to fill a DataSet wich i return in my WebService. The problem comes when i want to send an exception instead of the DataSet, since the stored procedure checks on the DB and returns an empty row the DataSet fills with nothing and does not send me to an Exception ... Now, i save all my exceptions in a log table in the same DB ... My question is, can i go to the Exception block if the SELECT values are empty??

Here is my Code

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Private", EnableSession = false)]
public DataSet M812(string p_transaction)
{
    string extran, enclosure, eDate;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTSSQL"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.sp_M812";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_trans", SqlDbType.NChar, 18).Value = p_transaction;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Entradas");
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        return ds;
    }
    catch(SqlException Ex)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTSSQL"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.sp_reqdataerrorlog";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_inTrans", SqlDbType.NChar, 12).Value = p_transaction;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@vo_enclosure", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@vo_trans", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        enclosure = "" + cmd.Parameters["@vo_enclosure"].Value;
        extran = "" + cmd.Parameters["@vo_trans"].Value;

        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTSSQL"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd2.Connection = con2;
        cmd2.CommandText = "dbo.sp_errorlog";
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_inTrans", SqlDbType.NChar, 12).Value = p_transaction;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_enclosure", SqlDbType.NChar, 6).Value = enclosure;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_trans", SqlDbType.NChar, 18).Value = extran;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_method", SqlDbType.NChar, 6).Value = "812";
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = "SQL Error: " + Ex.Message;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@vo_message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@vo_errorDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        con2.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con2.Close();
        cmd2.Connection.Close();
        eDate = "" + cmd2.Parameters["@vo_errorDate"].Value;

        SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTSSQL"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd3.Connection = con3;
        cmd3.CommandText = "dbo.sp_selecterrorlog";
        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@p_trans", SqlDbType.NChar, 18).Value = p_transaction;
        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@p_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = eDate;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "ErrorLog");
        con3.Open();
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con3.Close();
        cmd3.Connection.Close();
        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTSSQL"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.sp_reqdataerrorlog";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_inTrans", SqlDbType.NChar, 12).Value = p_transaction;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@vo_enclosure", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@vo_trans", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        enclosure = "" + cmd.Parameters["@vo_enclosure"].Value;
        extran = "" + cmd.Parameters["@vo_trans"].Value;

        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTSSQL"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd2.Connection = con2;
        cmd2.CommandText = "dbo.sp_errorlog";
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_inTrans", SqlDbType.NChar, 12).Value = p_transaction;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_enclosure", SqlDbType.NChar, 6).Value = enclosure;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_trans", SqlDbType.NChar, 18).Value = extran;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_method", SqlDbType.NChar, 6).Value = "812";
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = "WEB Error: " + Ex.Message;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@vo_message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@vo_errorDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        con2.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con2.Close();
        cmd2.Connection.Close();
        eDate = "" + cmd2.Parameters["@vo_errorDate"].Value;

        SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTSSQL"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd3.Connection = con3;
        cmd3.CommandText = "dbo.sp_selecterrorlog";
        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@p_trans", SqlDbType.NChar, 18).Value = p_transaction;
        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@p_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = eDate;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "ErrorLog");
        con3.Open();
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con3.Close();
        cmd3.Connection.Close();
        return ds;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have connection and command objects in your `catch` blocks?  Also, naming both exceptions 'ex' is a bad and confusing practice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment man, i will polish those details, its always cool to have a different point of view :3

Comment: I am always happy to help and share knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can check if the `DataSet` has any rows in any table:

```
bool hasRows = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Any(table => table.Rows.Count != 0);
```

Now you have a choice as to how to get the error data returned to the caller:

1. Pull out the error building logic into a separate method that your exception `catch` handler block and your `if` condition can both call, like this:

   ```
   private void BuildAndReturnErrorDataSet()
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTSSQL"].ConnectionString);
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
       cmd.Connection = con;
       cmd.CommandText = "dbo.sp_reqdataerrorlog";
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_inTrans", SqlDbType.NChar, 12).Value = p_transaction;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@vo_enclosure", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@vo_trans", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
       cmd.Connection.Close();
       enclosure = "" + cmd.Parameters["@vo_enclosure"].Value;
       extran = "" + cmd.Parameters["@vo_trans"].Value;

       SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTSSQL"].ConnectionString);
       SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
       cmd2.Connection = con2;
       cmd2.CommandText = "dbo.sp_errorlog";
       cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_inTrans", SqlDbType.NChar, 12).Value = p_transaction;
       cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_enclosure", SqlDbType.NChar, 6).Value = enclosure;
       cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_trans", SqlDbType.NChar, 18).Value = extran;
       cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_method", SqlDbType.NChar, 6).Value = "812";
       cmd2.Parameters.Add("@p_message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = "WEB Error: " + Ex.Message;
       cmd2.Parameters.Add("@vo_message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
       cmd2.Parameters.Add("@vo_errorDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
       con2.Open();
       cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con2.Close();
       cmd2.Connection.Close();
       eDate = "" + cmd2.Parameters["@vo_errorDate"].Value;

       SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTSSQL"].ConnectionString);
       SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
       cmd3.Connection = con3;
       cmd3.CommandText = "dbo.sp_selecterrorlog";
       cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd3.Parameters.Add("@p_trans", SqlDbType.NChar, 18).Value = p_transaction;
       cmd3.Parameters.Add("@p_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = eDate;
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       da.Fill(ds, "ErrorLog");
       con3.Open();
       cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con3.Close();
       cmd3.Connection.Close();
       return ds;
   }

   if(!hasRows)
   {
       // Call error data set building logic
       BuildAndReturnErrorDataSet();
   }

   catch (Exception Ex)
   {
       // Call error data set building logic
       BuildAndReturnErrorDataSet();
   }
   ```
2. Raise exception if `hasRows` is false - not recommended as this is using exception handling to cause program control flow, but it technically will work.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me some ideas, ill try them out and see if this Works for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2816654 - great, glad it gave you some ideas. If you feel this answer helped you, then feel free to accept the answer and up-vote the answer when you can. :-)

Comment: Can not up vote it since im new at this fórum ... But answer accepted, thanks man.

Comment: @user2816654 - I think you need 15 reputation to up-vote. You will be there soon. :-)